How to properly create a volume for maven repository in Docker Compose?
I use the maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17 base image for my Docker containers publisher and consumer. In docker-compose.yaml I created a volume m2_volume:/root/.m2 to reuse the maven dependencies after each build.
docker-compose.yaml
services:
  publisher:
    build: ./publisher/
    networks:
      - messaging
    depends_on:
      rabbitmq:
          condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - m2_volume:/root/.m2
  consumer:
    build: ./consumer/
    networks:
      - messaging
    depends_on:
      rabbitmq:
          condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - m2_volume:/root/.m2
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:4.0.4-management-alpine
    networks:
      - messaging
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 5671:5671
      - 15672:15672
      - 4369:4369
      - 25672:25672
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "rabbitmq-diagnostics", "check_running"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      start_period: 30s
      retries: 3
networks:
  messaging:
    name: messaging
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  m2_volume:

When you run the compose file the maven dependencies start downloading and the applications run. But if run the compose file in the second time the maven dependencies start downloading again instead of reusing the artifacts from m2_volume:/root/.m2. I build my compose file using docker compose build --no-cache.
In my Dockerfiles I use mvn clean package to build the applications.
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN mvn clean package

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "target/app.jar"]


Does Maven docker cache dependencies answer your question?  Of note, the .m2 directory will only be used while building an image, but volumes: will only be used while running a container, and so you need to use the Docker builder's caching capabilities and not volumes.

@DavidMaze yes it answers my question. Thank you for the explanation.
